# Using .Formula with variable in last ListRows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use .Formula to insert formula into newly created last ListRows.
This snippet of code works

```
oNewRow.Range(0, 2).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME])<=1,""100-"" & CHAR(72) & ""-0""&COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME]),)"
```

This formula goes in No Problem, but I need the CHAR() to be represented by a variable.

Thank you.

```
Dim cChr As Integer
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim tblRows As Integer
Dim oNewRow As ListRow



Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("100-0-00").ListObjects("TBL_tertiary129")


Set oNewRow = tbl.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

tblRows = tbl.ListRows.Count


cChr = (65 + tblRows - 2) 'Increment alpha value based on position

MsgBox (Chr(cChr))


oNewRow.Range(0, 2).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME])<=1,""100-"" & CHAR(" & cChr & ")""-0"" &COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME]),)" 'Problem with Formula within Quotes
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: 1004 Application-defined or object defined error

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing an ampersand. Currently if `cChr` is set to 72 your formula would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME])<=1,"100-" & CHAR(72)"-0" &COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME]),)
```

You'll see there is no ampersand after the `CHAR(72)` to concatenate it with the `"-0"`.  Instead:

```
oNewRow.Range(0, 2).Formula = "=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME])<=1,""100-"" & CHAR(" & cChr & ") & ""-0"" &COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME]),)"
```

This is easily catchable if you echo out to the immediate pane the results of your concatenation:

```
debug.print "=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME])<=1,""100-"" & CHAR(" & cChr & ")""-0"" &COUNTIF(A:A,[@PRODNAME]),)"
```

Before slinging it over to the range's `.formula` and picking up some esoteric excel error.

Comment: Thanks JNevill! That was it. One missing "&". Most appreciated!!